# Add Forgot password link to email signin with passwordless template

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to add a Forgot Password link to the email signin page, like so:

[image]

I'm using the passwordless starter pack that splits Phone and Email signups/signins in different screens.

My problem is that I cannot find the right place to make the link appear in the email signin page. I followed the embedded password reset but I can only add it in the main page where it asks the user to type in his phone or email.

Here's the Relying party policy that I need to modify to add the password link SignUpSignInWithPhoneOrEmail:

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail"
  DeploymentMode="Development"
  UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_Phone_Email_Base_Extension</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail-Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="signuporsignin-phone-email">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninPhoneEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithEmail" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithPhone" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AppleExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Phone-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Apple-OIDC" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithPhone" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ChangePhoneNumber" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage-ChangePhoneNumberClaimsProviderSelection" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- If the user comes from phone signup, collect recovery email address  -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isEmailSignUp</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isChangePhoneNumber</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithPhone_CollectEmailAddress" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber_CollectEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Debugging Step (useful for the app insight)-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Debugging Step to see the claim bag" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Debug-TechProfile" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
       <!-- Leave the rest of the template  -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="SignInWithPhoneOrEmail" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isChangePhoneNumber</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>hasFullProfile</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail-Custom" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="urkey" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

I have no clue what I need to modify to add the forgot password link since this email signin page is a separate screen different from the examples.

Comment: Github original issue: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a complete explanation on the original GH issue that explains how to add the link to any email signin screen. [GH issue answer here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/390#issuecomment-1099939186)